# Download attachment from Outlook 2013 using Python Script

Tags: python, outlook, jupyter-notebook, win32com

I want to have a python script to download any file with specified name but of any file format(it can be .txt, .csv, .pdf, .docx, .xlsx, .msg, etc.)
Currently, I have the following python code to download attachments from outlook 2013:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import datetime as date
import os.path

def attach(subject,name):
    outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
    all_inbox = inbox.Items
    val_date = date.date.today()
    sub_today = subject
    att_today = name
    for msg in all_inbox:
        if msg.Subject == sub_today:
             break
    for att in msg.Attachments:
        if att.FileName == att_today:
             break
    att.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + att.FileName)
    print "Mail Successfully Extracted"
```

If I make it specific for certain type of attachment, it works fine.

```
attach('Hi','cr.txt')
```

but I want to do something like this:

```
attach('Hi','cr.*')
```

so it can download attachment with name 'cr' but of any file format.

Can anyone suggest a way around it, that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, This code checks only for the mail received today `val_date = date.date.today()`  I want to check attachments in mail received in last 7 days. How should I do that? I searched for **win32com** documentation but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :)

```
import win32com.client, datetime
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import datetime as date
import os.path

def checkTime(current_message):
    date_filter_unformated = datetime.date.today() - date.timedelta(days=7)
    date_filter = date_filter_unformated.strftime("%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S")
    message_time = current_message.ReceivedTime
    df_list = list(date_filter)
    mt_list = list(str(message_time))
    df_month, mt_month = int(''.join([df_list[0],df_list[1]])), int(''.join([mt_list[0],mt_list[1]]))
    df_day, mt_day = int(''.join([df_list[3],df_list[4]])), int(''.join([mt_list[3],mt_list[4]]))
    df_year, mt_year = int(''.join([df_list[6],df_list[7]])), int(''.join([mt_list[6],mt_list[7]]))
    if mt_year < df_year:
        return "Old"
    elif mt_year == df_year:
        if mt_month < df_month:
            return "Old"
        elif mt_month == df_month:
            if mt_day < df_day:
                return "Old"
            else:
                CurrentMessage(current_message)
                return "Pass"
        elif mt_month > df_month:
            CurrentMessage(current_message)
            return "Pass"

def CurrentMessage(cm):
    print cm.Sender, cm.ReceivedTime


def getAttachment(msg,subject,name):
    val_date = date.date.today()
    sub_today = subject
    att_today = name#if you want to download 'test.*' then att_today='test'
    for att in msg.Attachments:
        if att.FileName.split('.')[0] == att_today:
            att.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + att.FileName)


def attach(subject,name):
    outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
    all_inbox = inbox.Items
    all_inbox = all_inbox.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    sub_today=subject

    for current_message in all_inbox:
        if checkTime(current_message) == "Pass" and  current_message.Subject == sub_today:
            getAttachment(current_message,subject,name)      
    print "Mail Successfully Extracted"
```

Comment: will it download attachment based on attachment name, and not on the file extension?

Comment: i ran it, and it raised error: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError 
<ipython-input-5-88299a63b0cf> in <module>()
----> 1 attach('Revised list','metrices_V7')

<ipython-input-4-aba9c3648b88> in attach(subject, name)
     48     sub_today=subject
     49 
---> 50     for current_message in all_inbox:
     51         if checkTime(current_message) == "Pass" and  current_message.Subject == sub_today:
     52             getAttachment(current_message,subject,name)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: It will download on attachment name.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tanmay. Changing sub_today to subject. Sorry about that in line number 52 will do.

Comment: i put the filenamewith extension, `attach('test_mail','50YearsDataScience.pdf')` but still I'm getting the same error
`TypeError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)` in `---> 50     for current_message in all_inbox:`
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
PS: removed unnecessary lines from error log

Answer (score 0):

using fnmatch module in python , just check the filename as below

if fnmatch.fnmatch(att.FileName, att_today)

Usage: attach('Hi','cr.*')

Pattern Meaning
*   matches everything
?   matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any character not in seq